# Flutter: How to get the latest date from array of objects in API side?

Tags: android, flutter, asp.net-web-api

I use flutter in project.

I get array of objects from the server. Each object contains few properties and one of them is date property.

Here is the Array (in json) that I get from server:

```
{
    "drainageid": "",
    "datacount": 98359,
    "resultcount": 98359,
    "page": "",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
            "dateoflastinsp": null,
            "dateofinsp": "2001-10-10T00:00:00",
            "inspby": "SAW/ZAG"
        },
        {
            "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
            "dateoflastinsp": "2001-10-10T00:00:00",
            "dateofinsp": "2002-09-24T00:00:00",
            "inspby": "SAW+NBN"
        },
        {
            "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
            "dateoflastinsp": "2002-09-24T00:00:00",
            "dateofinsp": "2003-09-18T00:00:00",
            "inspby": "SAW/NBN"
        },
        {
            "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
            "dateoflastinsp": "2003-09-18T00:00:00",
            "dateofinsp": "2004-09-08T00:00:00",
            "inspby": "SAW/NBN"
        },
        {
            "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
            "dateoflastinsp": "2004-09-08T00:00:00",
            "dateofinsp": "2005-05-05T00:00:00",
            "inspby": "MZB/ASMG"
        },
        {
            "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
            "dateoflastinsp": "2005-05-05T00:00:00",
            "dateofinsp": "2006-05-04T00:00:00",
            "inspby": "MZB/ASZ"
        },
        {
            "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
            "dateoflastinsp": "2006-05-04T00:00:00",
            "dateofinsp": "2007-05-09T00:00:00",
            "inspby": "Ahmad/Haizul"
        },
        {
            "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
            "dateoflastinsp": "2007-05-09T00:00:00",
            "dateofinsp": "2008-05-07T00:00:00",
            "inspby": "Harzazi/Zulkornain"
        },
}
```

I need to get the latest date `dateoflastinsp` from the array among the `rows` list.

What is the way to get the latest date from array of objects in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List.sort` and compare the dates.

```dart
String jsonData = '''
  {
    "drainageid": "",
    "datacount": 98359,
    "resultcount": 98359,
    "page": "",
    "rows": [
      {
        "id": "DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01",
        "dateoflastinsp": null,
        "dateofinsp": "2001-10-10T00:00:00",
        "inspby": "SAW/ZAG"
      }...
 ''';


// Parse the JSON data
  Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);

  // Sort the rows by dateofinsp in ascending order
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(data['rows']);
  rows.sort((a, b) => DateTime.parse(a['dateofinsp']).compareTo(DateTime.parse(b['dateofinsp'])));

  // Print the sorted rows
  for (Map<String, dynamic> row in rows) {
    print(row);
  }
```

output

```
{id: DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01, dateoflastinsp: null, dateofinsp: 2001-10-10T00:00:00, inspby: SAW/ZAG}
{id: DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01, dateoflastinsp: 2001-10-10T00:00:00, dateofinsp: 2002-09-24T00:00:00, inspby: SAW+NBN}
{id: DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01, dateoflastinsp: 2002-09-24T00:00:00, dateofinsp: 2003-09-18T00:00:00, inspby: SAW/NBN}
{id: DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01, dateoflastinsp: 2003-09-18T00:00:00, dateofinsp: 2004-09-08T00:00:00, inspby: SAW/NBN}
{id: DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01, dateoflastinsp: 2004-09-08T00:00:00, dateofinsp: 2005-05-05T00:00:00, inspby: MZB/ASMG}
{id: DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01, dateoflastinsp: 2005-05-05T00:00:00, dateofinsp: 2006-05-04T00:00:00, inspby: MZB/ASZ}
{id: DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01, dateoflastinsp: 2006-05-04T00:00:00, dateofinsp: 2007-05-09T00:00:00, inspby: Ahmad/Haizul}
{id: DR/C1/IC/H/-/GPG/PU/-/RCP/01, dateoflastinsp: 2007-05-09T00:00:00, dateofinsp: 2008-05-07T00:00:00, inspby: Harzazi/Zulkornain}
```